# Pushing object to array in Javascript works but leads to error when function attempts to return it

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, typeerror

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
//The purpose is to return an array which displays all objects which share name:value pairs in 'collection' and 'source.'
var arr = [];
var temp = [];

for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {

    var n = 0;

    loop0:
    for (var j = 0; j < Object.keys(source).length; j++) {


      if (collection[i].hasOwnProperty(Object.keys(source)[j]) && collection[i][Object.keys(source)[j]] == Object.values(source)[j]  ) {

        for(var k = 0; k < Object.keys(collection[i]).length; k++) {

          if (Object.keys(source).includes(Object.keys(collection[i])[k])) {

            n += 1;

            }

          }

        if (n == (Object.keys(source)).length){

          arr.push(collection[i]);  //PROBLEM EXISTS HERE, seemingly.
                                    //If this is commented out no errors occur.        
          break loop0;
        }

      }

    }


  }

  console.log(arr);  //This logs the desired result.
  return arr;   //This returns a type error.
}

//This is what I use to test which prompts the type error.
console.log(whatIsInAName(whatIsInAName([{ "apple": 1 }, { "apple": 1 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }], { "apple": 1 })));
```

When I run this code the expected output is: [{
      apple: 1
    }, {
      apple: 1
    },  {
      apple: 1,
      bat: 2
}], and indeed, the console will read that output if the 'console.log(arr)' exists at the end there.

The problem I am running into is that if any object from the input has been pushed to the intended output array, 'arr,' then upon returning the function the console will log the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at whatIsInAName (biyohehake.js:13:32)
```

It will output this error despite logging to the console the desired contents of 'arr' immediately before attempting to return 'arr,' which appears to somehow be the problem. I am really just baffled that it can log the array but not return it; what am I missing?

Comment: You have an inner `whatIsInAName()` and an outer `whatIsInAName()` call. The outer one has no second argument. `source` is therefore undefined, which causes the error.: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/eh3wrskz/

Comment: Let this be a lesson to all on the dangers of copy-pasting and tunnel vision.

Comment: Also, this algorithm can be shortened considerably provided this is just about common keys and values: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/yzf7bsmr/

Comment: Of course, I have removed the redundancies now that I'm no longer paranoid I was making a fundamental error within the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 //This is what I use to test which prompts the type error.
 console.log(
   whatIsInAName(
     whatIsInAName(
       [{ "apple": 1 }, { "apple": 1 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }],
       { "apple": 1 }
     ),
     /*ARGUMENT 2*/
   )
 );
```

The outer `whatIsInAName` function call doesn't have a 2nd argument.